# How to use prettier/standalone in the browser with Rails app and Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, prettier

**TLDR: I NEED TO USE PRETTIER STANDALONE WITH WEBPACK IN RAILS 5.**

Prettier docs: https://prettier.io/docs/en/browser.html

*I can make it work with the cdn, but I don't want to use the cdn.*

I need to format css in a text editor in the browser. I want to use Prettier Standalone for this.

The app is Rails 5.2 that uses Webpacker and Vue.

I am following the documentation here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/browser.html

I run `yarn add prettier`

Then, in my .js file I have:

```
import prettier from 'prettier';
import parserCss from 'prettier/parser-postcss';

prettier.format(".foo{color: red;}", {
  parser: "css",
  plugins: [parserCss],
});
```

This works in my local development environment, but when I try to deploy the application, the build fails during Webpack compile.

I think I need to configure my webpack or something. If you need more information just let me know and I will update the question.

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: I don't get a compilation error in my local env. During the deploy, the error is just a javascript heap memory error. But I have increased memory and still get that same error. So, I suspect that the heap memory error isn't very helpful for debugging the issue.